# get 400K data from tables in Spring MVC within some sec

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC and I need to get more than `400k datas` by my table where i also using JOIN in mysql query.

What I actually have is a Controller that returns which contains a List. I call the Controller using AJAX.

The problem with my solution is that I'm not able to get the data of List with in seconds it take more than 5 minutes to load on JSP page.

In page Jquery..

```
$(document).ready(function ajaxPost() {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
  data: page,
      url: "allListAjax",
      success: function(list) {
        //here i get responce list and page which takes 5 minutes
  }//success
 }//ajax
}//ready
```

In Controller..

```
@RequestMapping(value="/allListAjax")
public @ResponseBody IVRRouteReportWrapper dashoardAjax(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer page) {
    IVRRouteReportWrapper wrappObj= new IVRRouteReportWrapper();
    List<IVRRouteReport> list = ivrRouteServiceInterface.getAllIVRRouteReport(page);
wrappObj.setIVRouteReportList(list);
    wrappObj.setPage(page);
return wrappObj;
}
```

here, `IVRRouteReportWrapper` is a Domain model which contains setters and getters of  List and page.

In Service Implementation...

```
 public List<IVRRouteReport> getAllIVRRouteReport(Integer page) {
      return ivrRouteDAOInterface.getAllIVRRouteReport(page);
    }
```

In Dao Implementation...

```
public List<IVRRouteReport> getAllIVRRouteReport(Integer page) {
if(page==null) {
    page = 0;
}else {
    page = page*200;
}
String strqry= "SELECT c.caller_id_number as caller_id_number, c.destination_number as destination_number,"
        +" c.created_time as created_time, vbDtmf.digit as dtmf FROM VoiceBroadcastDTMF vbDtmf "
        +"LEFT JOIN cdr c ON vbDtmf.uuid=c.orig_id ORDER BY c.created_time DESC";

Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(strqry)
              .addScalar("caller_id_number", new StringType())
              .addScalar("destination_number", new StringType())
              .addScalar("created_time", new StringType())
              .addScalar("dtmf", new StringType())
              .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(IVRRouteReport.class))
              .setFirstResult(page)
              .setMaxResults(200);

 List<IVRRouteReport> ivrRouteReportList =(List<IVRRouteReport>) query.getResultList();
 getSession().flush();
 return ivrRouteReportList;
 }
```

> Is there any way to return this List Fast on jsp page ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index the "created_time" column and also omit not required fields by specifying only the required fields in the query as below

```
String strqry= "SELECT c.caller_id_number as caller_id_number, c.destination_number as destination_number,"
    +" c.created_time as created_time, vbDtmf.digit as dtmf FROM VoiceBroadcastDTMF vbDtmf "
    +"LEFT JOIN (SELECT caller_id_number , destination_number , created_time FROM cdr) as c ON vbDtmf.uuid=c.orig_id ORDER BY c.created_time DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for pagination.

Refer [spring-mvc-pagination](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-pagination-example/)

Comment: Thanks to reply Dear, i already set pagination, in 200 datas per batch but it takes time 4 to 5 minutes..

Comment: try with async: false in ajax request.

Comment: actually i never use it. can you gives some hint about asyn: false and how it works..Thanks again.

Comment: see this https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-AJAX-Async-False-Synchronous-call-and-Async-True-Asynchronous-call-difference.aspx

Comment: when we go with async: false it blocked the browser(Scrolling) and i cannot do anything until the call is completed. and its take same time like 4 to 5 minutes

Comment: does it take same time for loading data using jsp load instead of ajax?

Comment: Hello @Alien, yes it take same time for loading data using jsp load instead of ajax.